# Web services in SAP are available by default?

Tags: web-services, .net-core, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to integrate data from the SAP in .NET Core application. Standard SAP .NET connector doesn't support .NET Core, so the only way to connect seems to be consuming web services published by SAP.

I have heard somewhere, that web services are not standard SAP feature and only some instances has the ability to publish ABAP web services. Is it true?

Is .NET Core web service client able co consume SAP web service?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are *SOAP* web services.

Comment: Yes, not all SAP instances have SOAP web services, or yes, it is possible to consume them by .NET client? :-)

Comment: Did you check the docs? Did you check the option to [add connected services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)? Did you try it? `SAP web service` means little. It doesn't say what that service is. SOAP is the only standard. REST is essentially a generic description, not a standard.

Comment: SAP was one of the first big companies to build services using WCF so some of the services you want to call may be WCF and thus a lot easier to use. You haven't explained *which* services you want to use though. SAP is big and old, and different services in different versions will use different technologies. What was implemented as SOAP 5 years ago may be a REST service in the version you want to use

Comment: I don't have access to any (specific) SAP instance right now, unfortunately. What I am trying to find is, if there is inbuild SAP behavior (ready in all instances as standard part of the SAP system) to publish SOAP/REST service I could consume by .NET Core app.

Comment: `Is .NET Core web service client able co consume SAP web service?` this should be separate question that has nothing to do with SAP, it concerns .NET Core feature set, not SAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we speak about SAP ERP (ECC) they are practically standard. REST services are available [since SAP Netweaver 7.40](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/16/usage-of-the-abap-rest-library-sapbasis-740/) and SOAP services are available since ancient times.

Generally, [SAP Netweaver Gateway](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/24/a-simple-overview-on-sap-netweaver-gateway/) contains full OData implementation and is used for exposing SAP data to external systems, however REST [can be used without GW too](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/10/rest-web-services-without-gateway-server-and-client-with-just-two-custom-abap-classes/).

If we speaking about SAP Cloud solutions and other products even more integration options are available many of which are more advanced than services. For example, [SAP Cloud Connector](https://blogs.sap.com/2015/07/13/cloud-connector-a-brief-guide-for-beginners/)